# Preencher input de acordo com a resposta de outro input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Boa tarde, eu tenho o seguinte código no meu fomulário:

```
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label">{{ trans('app.select_client')}} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <select ng-model="cliente" class="form-control" name="cliente" id="cliente" required ng-init="cliente = '{{ old('cliente') }}'">
            <option value="">{{ trans('app.select_client')}} </option>  
                @foreach($clientes as $data)
                     <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->nomeCliente}}</option>
                @endforeach
           </select>

  </div>


<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
     <label class="control-label" >{{ trans('app.for')}}<span class="spancolor">*</span> </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="contato" ng-model="contato" name="contato" ng-init="contato='{{ old('contato') }}'" placeholder="{{ trans('app.contato')}}" required>     
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label" >{{ trans('app.cc')}}<span class="spancolor">*</span> </label>         
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="cc" ng-model="cc" name="cc" ng-init="cc='{{ old('cc') }}'" placeholder="{{ trans('app.cc')}}" required>                            
</div>
```

Eu preciso fazer com que  no input id="contato" aparecçla o email do cliente selecionado no select id="cliente"

Minha função no controller

```
function getContatos(Request $request){

        $value = $request->get('value');
        $contatos = DB::table('clients')->select('contatos')->where('id', $value)->get();
        $cc = DB::table('clients')->select('cc')->where('id', $value)->get();
        echo $contatos;
        echo $cc;

        //return view('dashboard.dashboard_user',compact('contatos','cc')); 


    }
```

Quando coloco o return da erro
O que eu preciso retornar e mostrar na view é $contatos e $cc

```
$('select[name=cliente]').change(function () {

    associaInput();
  var value = $(this).val();
  var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('cliente.getContatos') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{value:value, _token:_token},
        success:function(result){
            alert("success");
            $("#contato").append($('#contato').val(value));
        }

    })
});
```

função da view

```
Route::post('getContatos', 'DashboardController@getContatos')->name('cliente.getContatos');
```

Rota

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'clients';
        protected $fillable = ['nomeCliente', 'contatos', 'cc', 'obscontatos', 'horarioInicial', 'horarioFinal', 'observacao', 'analistapreferencial', 'servicos'];
        protected $casts = [
             'cc' => 'array', 'obscontatos' => 'array', 'contatos' => 'array',
        ];

    }
```

Model de Clients

Comment: Na vdd acho que vc vai ter que utilizar AJAX pra pegar o nome do cliente e fazer esse if com javascript.

Comment: Já utilizaste variável auxiliar? guardar sempre o nome anterior no decorrer do cilclo ?

Comment: Bom dia, poderia explicar melhor o pq de ter o segundo foreach percorrendo o mesmo array. Eu não consegui entender, talvez explicando melhor eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: No primei input eu percorro o array para pegar o {{$data->nomeCliente}} e no segundo o valor de {{$data->contatos}}

Comment: Só que ali no segundo input eu preciso comparar {{$data->nomeCliente}} com o value do primeiro input.

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus  o nome do cliente eu já consigo pegar e mostrar no javascript, mas não sei como irei acessar o array $clientes no java script para fazer a varredura.

Comment: @Lorena na minha resposta queria que você postasse como vem o retorno da request, no console.log() que coloquei

Comment: @JoanMarcos jquery.js:10261 GET http://localhost/monitoramento/public/getContatos?value=1&_token=wfzBV0Yzb2r2E6GPuTVeWJJjLBhibMVPf7ozT7HS 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Lorena tem como conseguir o log da mensagem de erro ? para ver o que realmente deu errado

Comment: @JoanMarcos
{,…}
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\monitoramento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
line: 664
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contatos, cc' in 'field list' (SQL: select `contatos, cc` from `clients` where `id` = 3)"
trace: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]

Comment: @JoanMarcos Não entendo pois, a conexão com o banco e as colunas estão corretas.

Comment: posta sua model de clients :D

Comment: @JoanMarcos Inseri na descrição da pergunta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92046/discussion-between-joan-marcos-and-lorena). @Lorena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade é bem tranquilo realizar tal barbárie, vamos lá \o/

---

### Ajax

```
$(document).on("change", "#cliente", function () {
 var value = $(this).val();
 var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
 $.ajax({
     url:"{{ route('cliente.getContatos') }}",
     method:"get",
     data:{value:value, _token:_token},
     success:function(result){
       console.log(result)//exibir o resultado da pesquisa no controller
       $("#contato").val(result[0]['contatos']);
       $("#cc").val(result[0]['cc']);
     }
  })
});
```

---

### Rota

Mude de `post` para `get` (`get` pq você só vai fazer consulta a base de dados e não alteração ou inserção)

```
Route::get('getContatos', 'DashboardController@getContatos')->name('cliente.getContatos');
```

---

### Controller

```
public function getContatos(Request $request) 
{
   $value = $request->get('value');

   $dadosCliente = DB::table('clients')
                       ->select('contatos','cc')
                       ->where('id', $value)
                       ->get();

  return response()->json($dadosCliente);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que utilize um ajax usando o evento `onChange()` no select dos clientes. Segue exemplo:

```
<div id="respostaAjax"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cliente").change(function(){
        type:"POST",
        data: $(this).val(),
        url: 'link/que/pesquisa/os/contatos/para/este/cliente.php'
        success: function(data){
            $("#respostaAjax").empty();
            $("#respostaAjax").append(data);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Após adicionar uma `<div>` que recebera a resposta do ajax que no caso será uma `select` contendo os contatos do cliente que vc selecionou anteriormente.
Qualquer dúvida edito a resposta pra adaptar-se a sua necessidade.
Explique melhor sua necessidade para que outros também possam te ajudar.

Comment: Eu fiz desta forma, mas o valor que vai para meu input de resposta é o valor do select id="cliente" e não, o email do cilente como desejo, o email do cliente já está sendo retornado no navegador, só não consegui retornar ele para view ainda.